# Associating additional information with a TensorBoard subgraph

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Using namescopes, it is possible to nicely organize the graph. However, it would often be beneficial to see some additional information about a subgraph (induced by a name_scope), for instance summarizing some attributes of the subgraph. Ops can have attributes, which are displayed in TensorBoard.

Is it possible to associate and display attributes of subgraphs in TensorBoard?

Comment: I don't think this is possible at the moment. But it sounds reasonable to me. I suggest you file a feature request on github. Or even better: implement it and send a pull request :-)

One complexity you will find is that the subgraphs don't really exist as part of the serialized GraphDef protocol buffer --- they are mostly just a naming convention on the nodes. So there is no obvious place to attach per-subgraph information.